# C++: Question about copy constructors

Tags: c++, memory-management, copy-constructor

I have a class where I use `this` to initialize a `void*` pointer. But the problem is, when I pass an instance of that class **by value**, the pointer will not change to the new address on the stack. So, I thought to override the copy constructor to reassign the pointer with the new address of `this`. But I need variables to call the super-class constructor, which I normally get by constructor-parameters, but I don't have them in my copy constructor...

I hope I explained well...

So the question is: can I keep the procedure of the default copy-constructor, where I add the part of reassigning the pointer? Or are there better alternatives?

Thanks

Here is a some code:

```
class GetsCopiedByValue : public SuperClass
{
    GetsCopiedByValue(Type1 *t1, Type2 *t2, float var1, /* A lot of other things I need */) :
         SuperClass(t1, t2), var1(var1)
    {
         t1->set_GetsCopiedByValue_Address(this);  // ***
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
{
    GetsCopiedByValue instance (t1, t2, 4.64, /* All the other things */);
    SomeType *t = new SomeType(instance); // <-- here, it gets copied by value,
}  // but the original "instance" goes (here) out of scope and the address 
   // I assigned (***) is not longer valid, so I have to
   // reassign the address to the new address, after copying it.
```

Comment: Can you post a code example? What does your code look like now?

Comment: Please post some code. And if you are using a void *, you are very probably doing it wrong.

Comment: "I have a class where I use this to initialize a void* pointer." It would be nice if you provided the code. Why do you even need void*, anyway?

Comment: "But the problem is, when I pass an instance of that class by value, the pointer will not change to the new address on the stack" ... I am quite sure I do not understand what you're saying here...

Comment: Alright, I'll rephrase that - please post some relevant and real  code.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that there are some parameters needed for the super class constructor and the OP is unsure how to get at these during copy construction since ordinarily they are passed into the subclass constructor. The whole `this` and `void*` stuff is incidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but you *can* actually call the superclass copy constructor in your copy constructor:

```
GetsCopiedByValue(GetsCopiedByValue const& other) :
     SuperClass(other), var1(other.var1)
{
     t1->set_GetsCopiedByValue_Address(this);
}
```

But I think that even if you omit this base-class constructor call, C++ will insert it for you.

Comment: +1: Er, yes, of course that's the other solution :) Note that if you omit the call you get a call to the default constructor for the base class so you do have to make it explicit.

Comment: If you omit the explicit call to the base constructor, it inserts an implicit call to the *default* base constructor, not necessarily the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store off the parameters when you first construct an object (probably in the superclass since that's what's using them) and then use them again on copy construction i.e. read them back out from the object you are copying from.

**Edit**

Better still, do as @Konrad Rudoplh [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430942/c-question-about-copy-constructors/3431011#3431011) and define and use a copy constructor for the base class too.